# Scope of State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm trying to understand what happens in the following code, the code behaves properly, but I'm trying to understand *why*.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import System.IO
import System.Environment

echoArgs :: [String] -> State Int [String]
echoArgs x = loopArgs x >> return x
      where loopArgs [] = return () 
            loopArgs s@(x':xs') = modify (+1) >> loopArgs xs'

main :: IO () 
main = do 
    argv <- getArgs
    let s = echoArgs argv
    mapM_ putStr' (evalState s 0) 
    putStrLn $ "\nNum Args = " ++ show (execState s 0) 
    where putStr' x = putStr $ x ++ " "
```

What I'm not understanding is why the state of the State monad does not get 'reset' with each successive call to loopArgs. Does the state get passed as a variable, with each `>>` and if so could someone show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the state get passed as a variable, with each >> and if so could someone show me how?

It does indeed. It's helpful to look at a toy implementation of the State monad.

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }

instance Monad (State s) where
  return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)

  State act >>= k = State $ \s ->
    let (a, s') = act s
    in runState (k a) s'

get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)

modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
modify f = get >>= \x -> put (f x)
```

When you bind using `>>=` or `>>` the accumulated state is threaded through as an argument to the function on the right hand side.

When you run `execState` or `evalState` it then just extracts either the resulting value or the state from the resulting tuple.

```
execState :: State s a -> s -> s
execState act = snd . runState act

evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
evalState act = fst . runState act
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there an example of how `>>` works (in the State monad), I understand how `>>=` works from your example, the state gets passed through each time.

Comment: ``>>`` is just a special case of ``>>=``, it's defined as ``m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k``

Comment: Oh right, but it still passes on the state, thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that Stephen!